# kadmin: Communication failure with server while initializing kadmin interface

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I have one node kerberos setup. I am able to query kdc using kadmin.local but when I try querying using kadmin( kadmin -p admin/admin@xxx.xxx.xxx) it fails with error:

```
kadmin: Communication failure with server while initializing kadmin interface
```

Kerberos services are running fine.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:88              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 :::88                   :::*                    LISTEN      - 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:88              0.0.0.0:*                           - 
udp6       0      0 :::88                   :::*                                - 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:750             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::750                  :::*                                -
```

I have started the kerberos services using command: /etc/init.d/krb5-admin-server start

krb5.conf

```
[realms]
    xxx.xxx.xxx = {
            kdc = devkdc.xxx.xxx
            admin_server = devkdc.xxx.xxx
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos admin works on port `749` by default. Make sure that is opened and can be accessed from the client hosts.

Also see here for other possible solutions:
https://serverfault.com/questions/803662/kerberos-error-while-initializing-kadmin-interface-from-admin-server/803994